# Shortest version of Lazy initialization

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

Is this the most laconic version of the code is show below? Is there any way to shorten it? Any syntactic sugar? Except `var`, I know about `var`.

```
Lazy<OrderEventItem[]> orderEventItems = new Lazy<OrderEventItem[]>(delegate
{
    return .......;
});
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Belongs on codereview stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var orderEventItems = new Lazy<OrderEventItem[]>(() => ...);
```

If you really want to get rid of the `new Lazy<OrderEventItem[]>`, you can create a generic static helper method:

```
static Lazy<T> CreateLazy<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    return new Lazy<T>(f);
}
```

and then your line becomes:

```
var orderEventItems = CreateLazy(() => ...);
```

Though, I find that less readable than the first approach.

Comment: thank you. I have just found absolutely same solution. The only nuance I had to create `LazyHelper` static non-generic class for it. Good answer.